# Spring beans with scope prototype

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

Suppose have following beach definition:

```
<bean id="singletonBean" class="...">
   <property name="instanceBean" ref="instanceBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="instanceBean" class="..." scope="prototype"/>
```

When I call:

```
singletonBean = context.getBean("singletonBean");

...some code...

singletonBean = context.getBean("singletonBean");
```

Would property `instanceBean` of `singletonBean` be initialized again or it would just use already created singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would just use already created singleton.

A prototyped inner bean of a singleton won't be recreated each time you get the singleton from context. The singleton and **all is references** are created one for all.

But `context.getBean("instanceBean");` would give you a new since scope is 'prototype'.

Answer (score 0):

instanceBean is set only once on startup, so you can get the `instanceBean` by `singletonBean.getInstanceBean()` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

When invoked `context.getBean("singletonBean")` always it contains the same instance of `instanceBean`, though the scope is `prototype` in the bean definition.

On the contrary if the container bean is of scope `prototype` and it refers to a bean which is defined with scope `singleton`, always the inner bean would be singleton. Eg:-

```
<bean id="outer" class="OuterBean" scope="prototype">
   <property name="innerBean" ref="inner" />
</bean>
<bean id="inner" class="InnerBean" scope="singleton"/>

OuterBean outer1 = (OuterBean) context.getBean("outer");
OuterBean outer2 = (OuterBean) context.getBean("outer");
```

Here both `outer1` and `outer2` will contain same instance of `InnerBean`.

In a multitheaded environment, if `innerBean` holds any shared data, it can lead to race condition.